# Can you use the typeof operator in selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

I want to do this

```
if (typeof(variable) == "undefined") {}
```

does this work in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can execute any javascript from selenium with the [getEval method](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html).

Comment: ok, that is what I thought but I always get confused with it. How what would it look like in this case?